# How can I use AutoPostBack inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, autopostback

I have two DropDownLists inside an UpdatePanel.

The values shown inside the second are dependent of the selectedValue on the first, so, I need AutoPostBack=true.

But, whenever the selected value in the first DropDownList is changed causes the UpdatePanel reload.

How can this be solved?

PS.: The UpdatePanel's UpdateMode property is set to Conditional.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, what you are describing sounds like correct behavior. AutoPostBack is true and the selected value changes, the UpdatePanel intercepts that postback and does it asynchronously. What's the problem?

Comment: What were the rules that you add in Page_Init? Thanks! Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding the Page_Init to execute some rules only at the first charge.